# When is "use lib PATH" evaluated?

Tags: raku

I would like to set the library load paths for Raku and Inline::Perl5 modules from within my script while minimizing the runtime impact.

I tried to replace

```
use lib $*PROGRAM.resolve.parent(2) ~ '/lib';
use lib $*PROGRAM.resolve.parent(2) ~ '/Inline/perl5';
```

which works with the following:

```
BEGIN {
    my $root = $*PROGRAM.resolve.parent(2);
    use lib "$root/lib";
    use lib "$root/Inline/perl5";
```

in order to save the second `.resolve.parent(2)` call.
This does not work as `$root` seems to be undefined when the `use lib` lines are being evaluated.

Comment: `$*PROGRAMM` appears to be a spelling error?  Did you mean `$*PROGRAM` ?  if so, does that fix the problem?

Comment: Ah, indeed … but no, just wrongly copied from the actual code. Will fix the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`use lib` is compile time. When you write

```
BEGIN {
    my $root = $*PROGRAM.resolve.parent(2);
    use lib "$root/lib";
}
```

the `use lib "$root/lib"` inside a `BEGIN` is essentially compile-compile time. What you would need to write is

```
BEGIN {
    BEGIN my $root = $*PROGRAM.resolve.parent(2);
    use lib "$root/lib";
}
```

or more succinctly

```
BEGIN my $root = $*PROGRAM.resolve.parent(2);
use lib "$root/lib";
```